# WebService or any RSS Feed which return latitude and longitude of the city

Tags: xml

Could anybody tell me about webservice or any RSS feed which wil return Latitude and Longitude corresponding to the city name given?? I had tried www.webservicex.net but couldn't get.I want get XML, which I can parse further to get Latitude and Longitude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps?

They have several ways to access their API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: NP :) Could you please flag this as your answer? (Click the green check mark)